# What causes iOS iCloud error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn’t be completed." Retrying after delay: 60

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, icloud

The iPhone/iOS app is using CoreData + SQLite (NSSQLiteStoreType) + iCloud iOS.  When the app starts on first install (or after deleting and reinstalling via xcode), and there is prior app data in iCloud from a prior installation or from other devices in the same account, the following error occurs, then a 60 second retry delay, then a successful migration to iCloud.  The result is that user of the app thinks that their data is lost when the app is upgraded.  However, after the 60 second delay, the data is restored.  The error and some code follows.

What causes this error?  Where can I learn more about this error?

> [4972:2014294] CoreData: iCloud: Error: initial sync notification returned an error (Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn't be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 12.)")
>
> [4972:2014294] -PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupWithRetry:: CoreData: Ubiquity:  : Retrying after delay: 60 Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn't be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 12.)"

Here is a code snippet and more detailed log to provide more context.

From the app delegate:

```
        - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 

            ... standard iCloud and app setup ...

            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

            ...

            ... query the db ...
        }

        /**
         Returns the managed object context for the application.
         If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
         */
        - (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

            if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
                return managedObjectContext;
            }

            NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
            if (coordinator != nil) {
                managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
                [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
            }
            managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;  
            return managedObjectContext;
        }

        ...

        /**
         Returns the managed object model for the application.
         If the model doesn't already exist, it is created by merging all of the models found in the application bundle.
         */
        - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

            if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
                return managedObjectModel;
            }
            managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];    
            return managedObjectModel;
        }

        ...

        /**
         Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
         If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
         */
        - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

            if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
                return persistentStoreCoordinator;
            }




            NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"myapp.sqlite"]];

            NSLog(@"App Store URL : %@", storeUrl);

            NSError *error = nil;
            persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];


            NSDictionary *storeOptions;
            storeOptions = @{
                             NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                             NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"AppCloudStore"
                             };
            #ifdef FREE
            storeOptions = @{
                             NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                             NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES,
                             NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: @"FreeAppCloudStore"
                             };
            #endif

            // Register for Notifications
            NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

            [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                                   selector:@selector(storesDidChange:)
                                       name:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification
                                     object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];

            [notificationCenter addObserver:self
                                   selector:@selector(persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:)
                                       name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
                                     object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];

            [notificationCenter addObserverForName:NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification
             object:self.persistentStoreCoordinator
             queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
             usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                 NSLog(@"Stores Will Change...");

                     if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
                         NSError *saveError;
                         if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&saveError]) {
                             NSLog(@"Save error: %@", saveError);
                         }
                     } else {
                         // drop any managed object references
                         [self.managedObjectContext reset];
                     }

             }];


            NSPersistentStore *store = [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl  options:storeOptions error:&error];

            if (store == nil || error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }


            NSURL *finaliCloudURL = [store URL];
            NSLog(@"Created persistent store okay.  Final iCloud URL is: %@", finaliCloudURL);

            return persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

    ...

    - (void)persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges:(NSNotification *)notification {

        NSLog(@"persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges: Called.  Content has changed via Core Data iCloud: *******************************************");

            // Received and merge updates from iCloud
            [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
            [self notifyAndRefreshAllDataDueToCloudEvent];
    }

    ...

    - (void)storesDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {

        // Tell me: why did my stores changes?
        NSNumber *transitionType = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey];
        int theCause = [transitionType intValue];

        NSLog(@"storesDidChange: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange Notification = %@", notification);

        switch (theCause) {
            case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountAdded: {
                NSLog(@"storesDidChange: Account Added");
                // account was added
            }
                break;
            case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeAccountRemoved: {
                NSLog(@"storesDidChange: Account Removed");
                // account was removed
            }
                break;
            case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeContentRemoved: {
                NSLog(@"storesDidChange: Content Removed");
                // content was removed
            }
                break;
            case NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeInitialImportCompleted: {
                NSLog(@"storesDidChange: Initial Import:");
                // initial import
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;

        }

    ... 

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"*****DidChangeByPersistentStoreChangesNotification"
         object:self];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"*****DidChangeByPersistentStoreChangesNotification"
         object:self];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         postNotificationName:@"*****DidChangeByPersistentStoreChangesNotification"
         object:self];

    }
```

More Detailed Log:

```
2015-05-12 10:22:23.367 [4972:2014228] storesDidChange: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange Notification = NSConcreteNotification 0x17005f470 {name = NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification; object = <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x170072100>; userInfo = {
    added =     (
        "<NSSQLCore: 0x12dd100b0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/****/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~****-7B78C4F2FDB2/FreeAppCloudStore/2***/store/app.sqlite)"
    );
}}
2015-05-12 10:22:23.409 [4972:2014228] -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~****:FreeAppCloudStore
Using local storage: 1
2015-05-12 10:22:23.410 [4972:2014228] Created persistent store okay.  Final iCloud URL is: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/****/store/app.sqlite
2015-05-12 10:22:23.477 [4972:2014228] AppTableViewController:viewWillAppear: enter
2015-05-12 10:22:23.478 [4972:2014228] getSharedAdBannerView: enter
2015-05-12 10:22:23.518 [4972:2014228] queryDidUpdate: MSMetadataQuery Notification: - NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
2015-05-12 10:22:23.519 [4972:2014228] queryDidUpdate: NSMetadataQuery returned 25 results
2015-05-12 10:22:23.524 [4972:2014228] setProcessTimer: 15.000000
2015-05-12 10:22:23.531 [4972:2014228] TableViewController:viewDidAppear: enter
2015-05-12 10:22:23.531 [4972:2014228] TableViewController:loadData (or reload): enter
2015-05-12 10:22:23.582 [4972:2014294] CoreData: iCloud: Error: initial sync notification returned an error (Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn't be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 12.)")
2015-05-12 10:22:23.594 [4972:2014294] -[PFUbiquitySetupAssistant finishSetupWithRetry:](826): CoreData: Ubiquity:  <PFUbiquitySetupAssistant: 0x12de18940>: Retrying after delay: 60
Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "The operation couldn't be completed. (BRCloudDocsErrorDomain error 12.)"
2015-05-12 10:22:23.854 [4972:2014228] didFailToReceiveAdWithError
2015-05-12 10:22:55.150 [4972:2014228] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2015-05-12 10:23:24.178 [4972:2014228] queryDidUpdate: MSMetadataQuery Notification: - NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification
2015-05-12 10:23:24.178 [4972:2014228] queryDidUpdate: NSMetadataQuery returned 25 results
2015-05-12 10:23:25.039 [4972:2014228] Stores Will Change...
2015-05-12 10:23:25.101 [4972:2014228] storesDidChange: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChange Notification = NSConcreteNotification 0x170254940 {name = NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification; object = <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x170072100>; userInfo = {
    NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousTransitionTypeKey = 4;
    added =     (
        "<NSSQLCore: 0x12dd100b0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/****/FreeAppCloudStore/20EF5D1C-4748-4AB2-BCE1-91B228437D77/store/app.sqlite)"
    );
    removed =     (
        "<NSSQLCore: 0x12dd100b0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/*****/store/app.sqlite)"
    );
}}
2015-05-12 10:23:25.101 [4972:2014646] -[PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntryMetadata setUseLocalStorage:](808): CoreData: Ubiquity:  mobile~*****FreeAppCloudStore
Using local storage: 0
```

Comment: Looks like it is working as expected which is as follows:
- Device opens the iCloud store
- Core Data creates a temporary local store and makes it available to the app (Using local storage: 1 message) immediately
- Core Data then creates an iCloud store (local copy) and downloads any base store data and log files and imports them
- Then Core Data merges the temporary store with the local iCloud store and switches the app to use this (Using local store: 0 message)

And Core Data errors could be related to waiting for the iCloud base store and logs to be downloaded.  Usually information only.

Comment: The app with iCloud/NSSQLiteStoreType is working perfect with the exception of the 60 second timeout described.  I don't think iCloud should need to error then retry in 60 seconds, "Retrying after delay: 60"  I have app users commenting through email and reviews that they have lost their app data which I suspect is simply due to the timeout and them not waiting it out.  I hope someone may have seen these errors.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Apple does not provide any service level agreement stating that iCloud sync will occur within any defined timeframe.  In my testing wait periods can be much longer than 60s.  Do a metadata query to look for iCloud files that have not yet downloaded. Your user obviously needs to have access to iCloud to do this.  If so you can monitor the download status and once downloaded things are usually pretty quick.  Check out this site for some example applications.  http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/softw re-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: HI @BillBunting - did you ever come up with a fix for this? I've been having the exact same error and issues for the last 2 months as well. When I made a new version of my app and released it to the App Store (with no iCloud/Core Data changes), when I upgraded to that, I had my data all gone from the app. I didn't wait for the data to come in, I just panicked and pulled the app from the store, but I have no idea what the fix is. The critical thing is, I am getting the exact same error in Xcode when the app is launched for the first time with existing data in the store, etc.

Comment: @BillBunting So I've kept my app in a different country store so I can continue to test it.. I've just tested it again and even after waiting, the data doesn't ever appear. I have iCloud Drive enabled. I'd love to work with you on this if you're still having this issue, or to find out what was done if the issue is resolved

Comment: @amitsbajaj I have been unable to resolve the problem and many of my users have reported they lost the app data after upgrading the app which has resulted in many negative reviews.  I discovered that some users were able to "find" their data if they enabled iCloud and also made sure iCloud Drive was turned on.  I suspect the bug is related to Apple moving from Documents and Data to iCloud Drive.  I'm hoping  that new users will not have this problem moving forward.

Comment: @BillBunting Thanks for the reply and that's really a shame with the upgrade. I had to pull my app from the store (been out for 2 months) because of the loss of data. Do you have Twitter, where I could contact you and we could potentially work on this together? You're the only person I've found who has the same issue and it'll be great to perhaps work together to see what the issues are. I am convinced it's an iOS issue and change.

Answer (score 25):

I hope my answer can save a lot of time for those who run into this error.

This error occurs when the time between the removal and installation of the application is less than a certain interval. I dont know whether it is the same as for me, mine was 15 seconds.

Silly mistake, a waste of a few hours.

Comment: That's really interesting. Thanks for the answer here and although it wasn't my question, I'm having the same issue. Do you have any thoughts on the missing data with iCloud/Core Data? Though that might be a separate issue but the question has the same issues as me with that. When updating to the App Store version, all of the data is no longer in the app

Comment: At the same time there are some consequences when you ignore this error message. Test for the case where users add new records in between the “error period”. Sometimes these records will just disappear after iCloud starts to sync again.

Comment: That's explains a lot. Thanks, your answer it really helped.

Comment: I've been stuck on this issue for hours! I feel so stupid now. lol.. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Got stuck too. Anyway this won't happens in production. The time the user needs to delete and re download the app should be more than 15s.